# Custom print function yield from sub function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I customized the print function to print to console and also send print lines to an object so I can pipe them to a gui using a yield function.  This works fine, until my function calls a sub function and that sub function prints to console.  If I import my custom print into that subfunction, it doesn't work because that print is yielding results to the subfunction, not the original outerfunction.

Is there a way to yield result from my custom print directly back to the main function and skip this inceptionesque nightmare?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import __builtin__

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    import builtins
    import io
    from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)
    with io.StringIO() as buf, redirect_stdout(buf):
        builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)
        output = buf.getvalue()
    return output
```

Comment: You could just have used `builtins.print(*args, **kwargs, file=buf)` instead of using `redirect_stdout()`.

Comment: Not that it's clear what you are trying to do though. Normally `print()` returns `None`, so the vast majority of calls will not expect anything to be returned anyway. And no, you can't return to the caller of a caller instead. You just return.

Comment: What you really seem to want is to replace `sys.stdout` with an object that will write to the inherited standard output and your GUI. Then you can leave `print` alone. `sys.stdout = Delegator(sys.stdout, my_other_file)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding `print`, create an object that writes to two different files when you write to it. Something like

```
# I'm not sure if there are other methods you should override, but
# they would be similar.
class Delegator(io.TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, fh1, fh2):
        self.fh1 = fh1
        self.fh2 = fh2

    def write(self, txt):
        self.fh1.write(txt)
        self.fh2.write(txt)

    def flush(self):
        self.fh1.flush()
        self.fh2.flush()

sys.stdout = Delegator(sys.stdout, my_other_file)
```

Comment: I tried this method but I am getting error: "TypeError: write() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".  After I define Delagator I am running:

    console=''
    sys.stdout = Delegator(sys.stdout, console)
    print('hi')

Comment: Dumb mistake on my part; `def write(self, txt)`.

Comment: Thanks Chepner, this works now at the main level - but I am wondering if this will work inside a sub function, to send my_other_file to the front -end directly without  having to return it to main, and then return it again to GUI function.  Will I need to make my_other_file a global var or something for this to work?

Comment: I don't have enough information about your actual code to say one way or the other.

Comment: Can confirm, setting my_other_file as global does work to pipe print to print and GUI at same time, regardless of function level (main, function, subfunction, etc - it works at all levels)